# Javascript googleMaps api not working when in seperate file

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I have copied a piece of code from w3schools regarding google maps api.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script
src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDY0kkJiTPVd2U7aTOAwhc9ySH6oHxOIYM&sensor=false">
</script>

<script>
function initialize()
{
var mapProp = {
  center:new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742,-0.120850),
  zoom:5,
  mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);
}

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
</head>

<body>

</body>
</html>
```

When i place it in my html file it works.

However, if i try to place this piece of code inside a javascript file

```
function initialize()
{
var mapProp = {
  center:new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742,-0.120850),
  zoom:5,
  mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);
}

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

It does not work

Inside my html would be

```
    <script
    src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDY0kkJiTPVd2U7aTOAwhc9ySH6oHxOIYM&sensor=false">
    </script>
<script src = "~/Scripts/JScript.js"> </Script>
```

I also have tried taking this function out

```
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

to become

```
    <script
    src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDY0kkJiTPVd2U7aTOAwhc9ySH6oHxOIYM&sensor=false">
    </script>
<script src = "~/Scripts/JScript.js"> google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);</Script>
```

But it just doesnt seem to work

Comment: Try wrapping your js with $(document).ready()

Comment: Where is your element `googleMap` in `html`??

Comment: you can't place code inside a `<script>` tag with an external source, also have you checked your browser's console for any errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working code,

**HTML**

`map.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="map.js"></script>
        <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDY0kkJiTPVd2U7aTOAwhc9ySH6oHxOIYM&sensor=false">

        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="googleMap" style="width:500px;height:380px;"></div>

    </body>
</html>
```

**JS**

`map.js`

```
function initialize()
{
    var mapProp = {
        center:new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742,-0.120850),
        zoom:5,
        mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap")
        ,mapProp);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    initialize();
});
```

The order of including `script` tag is important. `js` files are loaded in the order they are included

If you check your console, you can see each `js` file is loaded one by one.

Answer (score 1):

important piece missing from your code. check your HtML body

```
<body>
<div id="googleMap" style="width:500px;height:380px;"></div>

</body>
```